# google analytics - missing OAuth2Native class

Tags: java, api, google-analytics, oauth-2.0

I am trying to run a simple example from https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api to access Google analytic data.

Downloaded the java api-library `google-api-java-client-1.17.0-rc.zip` from https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/downloads/list,

There example code show compilation error :

```
    private static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();

    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

    private static Analytics initializeAnalytics() throws Exception {
        Credential credential = OAuth2Native.authorize(
        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, new LocalServerReceiver(),
        Arrays.asList(AnalyticsScopes.ANALYTICS_READONLY));

        Analytics analytics = Analytics.builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY)
  .setApplicationName("Hello-Analytics-API-Sample")
  .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential)
  .build();
```

I added all the libraries in class path but the library doesn't seem to have some classes :

`OAuth2Native`

`AnalyticsScopes`

`Analytics`

But these classes are present on `http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/shared/shared-sample-cmdline/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/shared/cmdline/oauth2/OAuth2Native.java?repo=samples&r=89662bd8ab341647b3f0aab8ed6a4fb444f478c2`

Comment: I am also facing the same problem, have you found a solution to this?

Comment: I used `google-api-services-analytics-v3-rev81-java-1.17.0-rc.zip`, from [Google Analytics API Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/analytics/v3). This contains the Analytics classes and all the dependencies from the Google API Client as well. But _not_ the OAuth2Native class, which I am still looking for.

Comment: `AnalyticsScopes` and `Analytics` are the part of [Google Analytics API library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/analytics/v3).
`OAuth2Native` is an example. You should implement [authorization code flow](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2#Authorization_Code_Flow) on your own. I'd recommend you to take a look at [this good example](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/authorization).

Comment: Though if you want just to play with the examples, you may try to "fix" them like described in [this post](http://humphreysheil.blogspot.com/2012/07/fixing-google-analytics-api-v3-examples.html) (but I haven't tried it).

Comment: How did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend downloading the sources from the following link

```
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client.samples/
```

You'll have to use [mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/) in order to checkout the project.
Once it's downloaded it all runs smoothly and it shows you also an example of the authorization implementation.
It works with no dependency issues.